# How to display at bottom always?

Tags: android

Currently, I am displaying `ListView` items. Now I need to display some `TextView` at the bottom always. finally, my view should be like this.

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you show us the XML of your layout, and include the desired result in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout`

than use **`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`** to attach your View at the bottom of screen

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **EDIT** You can also achieve this using `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nilesh" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Some item are being hidden behind down layout

Comment: @john try to add some `android:paddingBottom="50dp"` to your listview

Comment: @ Nilesh Rathod Wow! 50dp not enough 200dp works better